# App crashes after reopening

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

Basically every time I close and reopen app it crashes when I open History tab. Im pretty sure its because of how i use NSUserDefaults. Can anyone guide me through?

What I noticed is that sometimes it opens History tab after reopening but if i add a new entry to the Nsuserdefaults it will crash, after I reopen it it will work fine and will show the previous entry or it will remove everything and keep the new entry only.

```
    //
    //  SecondViewController.swift
    //  Angelina
    //
    //  Created by Artiom Sobol on 1/3/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Artiom Sobol. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit

    class History: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
    {
        // test variable
        var test: MyHistory!
        // array to store unarchived history
        var newHistory = [MyHistory]()

        //outlet for tableview

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {

            //change the background
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "newBackground.jpg")!)
            super.viewDidLoad()


            if let savedPeople = defaults.objectForKey("MyHistory") as? NSData {
                newHistory = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedPeople) as! [MyHistory]
            }
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            return self.newHistory.count
        }

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
        {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("historyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! historyCell
            let person = newHistory[indexPath.item]
          //  let defaults2 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            print("This is count", newHistory.count)

          //  if let savedPeople = defaults.objectForKey("MyHistory") as? NSData {
        //        newHistory = //NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedPeople) as! [MyHistory]
//            }



           // cell.durationLabel.text = String(person.durationNumber)
            let (hour,minutes,seconds) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(person.durationNumber)

            if(seconds < 10 && minutes < 10)
            {
                cell.durationLabel.text = "0\(hour):0\(minutes):0\(seconds)"
            }
            else if(seconds > 9 && minutes < 10)
            {
                cell.durationLabel.text = "0\(hour):0\(minutes):\(seconds)"
            }
            else if(seconds > 9 && minutes > 9)
            {
                cell.durationLabel.text = "0\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
            }
            else if(seconds < 10 && minutes > 9)
            {
                cell.durationLabel.text = "0\(hour):\(minutes):0\(seconds)"
            }


            cell.kicksLabel.text = String(person.kicksNumber)

            return cell
        }


        func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
        {
            return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
        }


    }
```

I think i just realized that my array gets restarted after the app is turned off. thats why the table crashes cus it goes out of bounds..

this is my other file where the saving of the array happens.

```
import UIKit
class Kicks: UIViewController
{
  var count = 0 as Int
    var countKicks = 0 as Int
    var kickReached = false as Bool
    var pressedOnce = true as Bool
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var test: MyHistory!
    var dateString = " "

    @IBOutlet var timerLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var kicksLabel: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var dateDisplay: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var kickbutton: UIButton!

    var myHistoryArray: [MyHistory] = []
    var currentMyHistory: MyHistory!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.printTimestamp()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background13.png")!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

      @IBAction func kickButton()
    {

        //currentMyHistory.kicksNumber = 5
        kickbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "gold-button-heart-icon.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        if(pressedOnce == true)
        {
            pressedOnce = false
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("counter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        else if(kickReached == true)
        {

            //  let date = NSDate()
            //  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            // let timer_total = calendar.components([ .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)

        }
        else if(pressedOnce == false)
        {
            countKicks++
            kicksLabel.text = "\(countKicks)"
            if(countKicks == 10)
            {
                self.printTimestamp()
                kickReached = true
                timer.invalidate()
                kickbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pink-button-heart-icon.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                congratsAlert()

                currentMyHistory = MyHistory(kicksNumber: countKicks, durationNumber: count)

                myHistoryArray.append(currentMyHistory)


                test = myHistoryArray[0]

                print("countof array ",  myHistoryArray.count)

                printTimestamp() // Prints "Sep 9, 2014, 4:30 AM"

                //save data
                let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(myHistoryArray)
                let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                defaults.setObject(savedData, forKey: "MyHistory")
                clear()

            }
        }

    }

    func printTimestamp() {
        let timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
        print(timestamp)
        dateDisplay.text = "\(timestamp)"
    }



    // save countKicks, count, and stamp i
    func congratsAlert()
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulation", message: "Yay!!! Angelina kicked 10 times in less than 2 hours.",preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",style: .Default,handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in})
        alert.addAction(okAction)

        presentViewController(alert,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }

    func clear()
    {
        count = 0
        countKicks = 0
        kickReached = false
        pressedOnce = true
        timerLabel.text = "00:00:0\(count)"
        kicksLabel.text = "\(countKicks)"
    }

    func counter()
    {
        ++count
        let (hour,minutes,seconds) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(count)

        if(seconds < 10 && minutes < 10)
        {
            timerLabel.text = "0\(hour):0\(minutes):0\(seconds)"
        }
        else if(seconds > 9 && minutes < 10)
        {
            timerLabel.text = "0\(hour):0\(minutes):\(seconds)"
        }
        else if(seconds > 9 && minutes > 9)
        {
            timerLabel.text = "0\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
        }
        else if(seconds < 10 && minutes > 9)
        {
            timerLabel.text = "0\(hour):\(minutes):0\(seconds)"
        }
    }

    func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
    {
        return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace from the output

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181cd5900 0x181343f80 0x181bbbac4 0x1000feb5c 0x1000fdbd8 0x100112134 0x100062840 0x1000637a4 0x186d1931c 0x186d19484 0x186d087e8 0x186d1dfb0 0x186ab308c 0x1869c3778 0x1843d2b2c 0x1843cd738 0x1843cd5f8 0x1843ccc94 0x1843cc9dc 0x1869b9c78 0x181c8c588 0x181c8a32c 0x181c8a75c 0x181bb9680 0x1830c8088 0x186a30d90 0x1000617c4 0x18175a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: countof array 6

Jan 24, 2016, 14:33

countof array  1

Comment: array goes to 0 after turning off the app

Comment: Why are you updating newHistory array in cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: because otherwise i can't add anything to the cell. What you mean updating ? I am just unarchiving everything from the history

Comment: I changed that, but i still get wrong results, my tableView doesn't get updated for some reason

Comment: I noticed that my tableView only gets updated after i reopen the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says clearly:

'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Double check your array objects like `newHistory` has all the elements when you app starts

It seems

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.newHistory.count
    }
```

self.newHistory.count is not 0 so it will trigger `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, try add two break points inside `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so you can know what's goes wrong. Usually, if no data, `numberOfRowsInSection` will return 0 and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not be triggered.

You can also an exception point In Xcode BreakPoint navigator, so you can break at any exceptions. This is simple debug skills you need to master.

Comment: thats the problem, after i restart my app it looses all the data.. i can't figure out why

Comment: Don't you save your data to disk? You have to all when you app starts, re-fetch the data and then update your cell.

Comment: updated my quetsion, I saw you saved and try reload, but the point is, which function is trying to read an empty array. You have to add exception bp or manually add your bp to debug, it should be very easy to solve

Comment: i figured it out thank you !! :) my only problem is now, when i check history, it always shows me 1 entry behind unless i switch tabs twice without adding new entry, basically from what i understand tableView doesn't get updated or there are not enough rows ? idk :(

Comment: @TriscuitDelicious Not fully understand, but table view will not update your array, unless you told it to do it. Usually, when you update your array, you call `tableView.reloadData` to update table view.

Comment: Where do i call it from ? I added it in many places and nothing happens, If i add it in tableView, all i get is white spots instead of my entries